# Error in onCreate method (FragmentActivity)

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, oncreate

Please help! When I'm trying to write onCreate method.

Multiple markers at this line

- The method onCreate in type MainActivityParent can only set one of public / 
   protected / private

  - Method breakpoint:MainActivityParent [entry] - onCreate(Bundle)
  - overrides android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate

here:

```
 package com.example.seledkarelease1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.util.LangUtils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MainActivityParent extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, 
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener {

    private ChildrenLocations ch;
    private Polyline mMutablePolyline;
    private boolean isGetting = false;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String[] menuItems;
    private GoogleMap mMap; 
    private LinkedList<LatLng> locations = new LinkedList<LatLng>();
    private 


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_parent);

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // mMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        if (locations.size() > 1) {
            LatLng[] locs = new LatLng[locations.size()];
            locations.toArray(locs);
            PolylineOptions opt = new PolylineOptions().add(locs/*locs[locs.length - 2], locs[locs.length - 2]*/);
            mMap.addPolyline(opt.color(Color.RED).width(10));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLng(locs[locs.length - 1]));
        }
    }

    public void showLocation(View view) {
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please connect to the internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
    }



    public void loadPath(View view) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileNameField);
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(tv.getText().toString());
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            locations = new LinkedList<LatLng>();
            String res = "";
            String readString = buffreader.readLine();
            while (readString != null) {
                res += readString;
                readString = buffreader.readLine();
            }
            isr.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setUpMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        if(position==0||position==1)
        showNoticeDialog();     
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(MainActivityParent.this.getFragmentManager(),
                "NoticeDialogFragment");
    }

    public void onUserSetValue(String name, String pass)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        isGetting=true;
        String res = new Client().execute("8888", name + " " + pass).get();
        if (res.equals("-1"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User was not found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (res.equals("1"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User was succefully connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (res.equals("0"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isGetting=false;

    }

    /**
     * Callback called when disconnected from GCore. Implementation of
     * {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

but at the same method in another class there are not these errors.

Comment: more code, what is this Activity's name and what do you extend. (Also change from `protected` to `public`

Comment: I've tryied it. But have the same error.

Comment: Try cleaning your project, sometimes helps when encountering strange errors.

Comment: I have already cleaned and restarted eclipse

Comment: Sorry, I've found my mistake. Thank's everybody!

Comment: Another, sometimes odd work-around, is to remove the imports and let eclipse add them again.

Comment: Have got the same problem, it helps me there's no stupid questions !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a empty floating `private` in your member declaration. remove that.

`private LinkedList<LatLng> locations = new LinkedList<LatLng>();`

`private`